# Delphi class constructor for object initialization

Tags: delphi

I have developed a class and I need my object to be able to hold the "history" of what happened during the lifetime of the program.

```
type
 TPipelineSimulator = class
  private
   class var history: TStringList;
   class constructor Create;
   class destructor Destroy;
   //other code
  public
   class property bitHistory: TStringList read history;
   //other code
 end;
```

And the simple implementation is:

```
class constructor TPipelineSimulator.Create;
begin
 history := TStringList.Create;
end;

class destructor TPipelineSimulator.Destroy;
begin
 history.Free;
end;
```

The class `TPipelineSimulator` has a normal procedure (not class procedure) that adds strings to the `history` variable; in this way I can fill my stringlist and access it with this code:

```
for k := 0 to a.history.Count-1 do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(a.history.Strings[k]);
```

---

This is very useful because even if the object is created and then released (the usual `Free` inside try-finally) I still can access to the stringlist. I have two questions about class constructors and destructors.

1. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Class_Constructors) says that constructors are inserted automatically by the compiler into the initialization section. The opposite happens with destructors. Does this mean that if I called `var a: TPipelineSimulator;` inside a button onclick procedure the class constructor for `a` is called when the program starts? Or just when I call the procedure for the first time?
2. In case of an exception (maybe by mistake I go out of bounds in the stringlist) do I risk a memory leak?

In point 2 I mean something like this. If the StringList is filled with 1 item each time, at the beginning the code below causes an out of bounds error a few times:

```
showmessage(a.history.strings[10]);
```

Despite that I can still access the stringlist and I has really wondering if this code is dangerous.

Comment: Pointless reasoning about out of bounds errors. Just fix them. Your code is broken. Who cares whether or lot you leak in that case? You gave bigger problems. As for exceptions during initialization and finalization, that should not happen. You must make sure it doesn't. If it does, then you can't recover so again leaking is not your concern. The game is up.

Comment: So you are telling me that if an exception happen during the lifetime I can do nothing? (Since of course the destructor is not called automatically like usually happens with normal constructors/destructors)

Comment: If an exception happens, it happens. Of course you can do something. But it should not happen inside the class constructor and certainly not inside the class destructor.

Comment: No. I'm saying that you must not throw exceptions during initialization or finalization. And I also say that you must fix your bug. Don't have AVs. Don't have bounds errors. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Ok thank you, got it. I put that showmessage to try to understand how the class var behaved. I thought that after the error I wasn't able to show the items of the stringlist anymore with the for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Class constructors are executed with the initialization section of the unit in which the class is implemented - to be precise: immediately before the code in the initialization section. For the destructor it is the other way round. The initialization order of the units is determined by the compiler.

The difference to the initialization/finalization section code is that class constructors/destructors are executed only if the class is actually used inside the program.

2) As long as the class destructor is called, you don't get a memory leak (at least not from this stringlist).